# PI controller code implementation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand the integral term of the PI controller properly so i have simulated my a dummy PI controller through this code

```
e =[10 7 8 5 6 3 4 1 2 1];
kp = 0.4;
ki = 1.35;
Ts = 0.5;
I =0;
for i =1:10
    P = kp*e(i);
    I = I +e(i)*Ts;
    output(i)= P+(ki*(I));
end
```

now what I was thinking that would it make any difference that if integrate ki with the I term or should I multiply it in the end

```
e =[10 7 8 5 6 3 4 1 2 1];
kp = 0.4;
ki = 1.35;
Ts = 0.5;
I =0;
for i =1:10
    P = kp*e(i);
    I = I +e(i)*Ts*ki;
    output(i)= P+I;
end
```

and to my surprise they both had the same output , should this second code have different as I am saving multiplication of error with my ki in the second code , am I not understanding something really basic here ? I know I am doing some mistake in my dry run , can someone point that out ?

Answer (score 0):

The I-terms of the output in both versions of the code look equivalent to me:

I_output<sub>k</sub> = ki * Σ<sub>j=1</sub><sup>k</sup>(e<sub>j</sub> * Ts) = Σ<sub>j=1</sub><sup>k</sup>(e<sub>j</sub> *Ts * ki)

But please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing the same thing is both of them and hence they are same.

' 5.0000    8.5000   12.5000   15.0000   18.0000   19.5000   21.5000   22.0000   23.0000   23.5000' This is the vector I from the first case and you multiply with ki before add it with P.

Now in second case, you have already multiplied the ki with each and every Ts, hence the each value of I include the multiplication of ki as before. If you take a look at the newer values of I '6.7500   11.4750   16.8750   20.2500   24.3000   26.3250   29.0250   29.7000   31.0500   31.7250' you can understand they are all same.

The result will be different if you use 'I = (I +e(i)*Ts)*ki;' because now you are now multiplying ki with each and every time with the whole I.